# Error configuring flask app on apache server

Tags: flask, apache2, python-3.6

I am trying to set up a flask app for the first time on an apache server. But for I keep getting these errors -

```
Target WSGI script '/var/www/html/myproject/myproject.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
File "/var/www/html/myproject/myproject.wsgi"
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

But if I run `python app.py` on the `myproject` folder, the server starts:

```
* Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
```

My project, named `myproject`, contains these files -

```
Pipfile  
Pipfile.lock  
Utilities.py  
__pycache__  
app.py  
myproject.wsgi  
text.txt
```

Here is myproject.wsgi

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/html/mproject")
import app as application
```

Here is app.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
@app.route('/')
def test():
  return 'Hello'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is my conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com

    WSGIDaemonProcess myproject 
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/myproject/myproject.wsgi

    <Directory /var/www/html/myproject>
        WSGIProcessGroup myproject
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Please what am I doing wrong here?